# Lexical tokens in Lua

Tags: lua

From doc

The following strings denote other tokens:

```
 +     -     *     /     %     ^     #
 ==    ~=    <=    >=    <     >     =
 (     )     {     }     [     ]
 ;     :     ,     .     ..    ...
```

What # and ... mean?

Comment: Doesn't the manual explain them??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#` is a [length operator](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.7) and `...` is a [variable argument (vararg) expression](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.11).

Answer (score 0):

The `#` symbol is used to get the length of a collection (array, string, etc.)

```
 items = {"a", "b", "c", "d"}
 print(#items) -- 4
```

The `...` symbol means that a function has a variable number of parameters

```
function print (...)
  for i,v in ipairs(arg) do
    result = result .. tostring(v) .. "\t"
  end
end
```

Comment: `ipairs(arg)` is incorrect; should be `ipairs({...})` or better even use `select('#', ...)` to avoid issues with `nil` in parameters.

Comment: @PaulKulchenko what is the use of {} in ipairs({...}), why is not ipairs(...)?

Comment: Because `ipairs(...)` will pass the list of parameters to `ipairs` instead of a table to iterate. If the first element is a number, you'll get an error like `bad argument #1 to 'ipairs' (table expected, got number)`.

Comment: BTW—This is an inappropriate use of `ipairs` because `print("Now you see it", nil, "Now you don't")` won't iterate through the whole list.